# Add all whitelisted directories to an index

Tags: git, whitelist, subdirectory

A git repository contains two directories: A and B1.
This is the directory structure:

```
$ find -name "*.*" -print
./.git/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample
./.git/hooks/commit-msg.sample
./.git/hooks/post-update.sample
./.git/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample
./.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample
./.git/hooks/pre-push.sample
./.git/hooks/pre-rebase.sample
./.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample
./.git/hooks/update.sample
./A/a.txt
./A/A1/a1.txt
./B/b.txt
./B/B1/b1.txt
./C/c.txt
```

This is the .gitignore file, it whitelists directories A and B1:

```
$ more .gitignore
# exclude files and directories in top directory
/*

# include the A directory
!/A

# include the B directory
!/B
# exclude files and directories in B
/B/*
# include the B/B1 directory
!/B/B1
```

The gitignore file is based on last example in http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

From inside a whitelisted directory, how to add all whitelisted directories to the index?
This does not work:

```
$ git add / --dry-run
fatal: /: '/' is outside repository
```

This works from the top directory:

```
$ git add . --dry-run
add 'A/A1/a1.txt'
add 'A/a.txt'
add 'B/B1/b1.txt'
```

But from inside a whitelisted directory only that directory is added to the index (B1 is missing):

```
$ cd A
A$ git add . --dry-run
add 'A/A1/a1.txt'
add 'A/a.txt'
```

Similar results with:

```
A$ git add * --dry-run
add 'A/A1/a1.txt'
add 'A/a.txt'
```

I want a command to add all whitelisted directories from any whitelisted directory so I don't forget one.

Comment: Your "from inside a whitelisted directory" case is doing exactly what is expected - you say `git add .`, which means "add the current directory and it's children". It does not mean "traverse back to the root of the project and add the entire project". You might try `cd A; git add ..` instead, replacing with `../..`, `../../..`, etc. as appropriate depending on how deep A is in the hierarchy. Alternatively `git add $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With modern Git you can use `:/` "*top dir*" pathspec:

```
$ git add :/
```